# Usage of bm in beamer

Tags: beamer, bm

Why `bm` package gives me a problem in this beamer document?

```
\documentclass[landscape]{beamer}                           % COMANDI INIZIALI
\usepackage[italian]{babel}                             % sillabazione italiana
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                             % Per le lettere accentate IN UNIX E IN WINDOWS
\usepackage{ragged2e}                                   % giustifica
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    % Per allineare le equazioni
\usepackage{amssymb}                                    % Per le lettere dell'indicatrice (mathbb)
\usepackage{graphicx}                                   % Per le figure
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\renewcommand{\fontsubfuzz}{1.1pt}                          % Elimina i warning inutili

\justifying                                         % giustifica

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\date{29 Aprile 2015}
\author{Gabriele Mazza}
\title{title}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{use=frametitle, bg=frametitle.bg}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{use=framtitle, bg=frametitle.bg}

\begin{document}

\section{Presentazione modello ST-PDE}
\subsection{Caso senza covariate}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Presentazione modello ST-PDE}
L'obiettivo del modello è la stima di un campo spazio temporale per la descrizione della variabile risposta:
\newline
$\{\bm{p}_i = (x_i,y_i); i=1, \ldots , n\}$ punti nel dominio spaziale $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ \\
$\{t_j ; j=1, \ldots , m\}$ istanti di tempo in $[T_1,T_2]\subset \mathbb{R}$ \\
$z_{ij}$ osservazioni in $(\bm{p}_i,t_j)$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Texmaker says:

```
Process started
trying to make  PK font mathkerncmssi10 at 657 DPI
running miktek-makemf.exe
miktek-makemf: The mathkerncmssi source file could not be found. Running tt2pk.exe
miktek-makepk
: PK font mathkerncmssi10 could not be created
process exited with errors
```

And the pdf is not created.

Without the three math rows process exited normally

Comment: What problem are you seeing? This looks 'works for me' with the latest code.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: Your document works without error and gives a bold p in texlive 2014

Comment: Your document also works with MikTeX

Comment: I suspect this is an operating system folder permissions issue.  Unless you have a local texmf tree established, you must have write permission to the folder tree where Miktex was installed on your system in order for mikex-makefm.exe to run successfully.

Comment: but @DavidCarlisle, is it really a great idea to have a bitmap font in beamer output?  or *is* there a bold sans italic font with math kerning in tex live 2014?

Comment: @barbarabeeton for me it passes through a tangle of virtual fonts that I didn't follow exactly but the pdf ends up with (a subset of)  the type1 font SFSO1000 (part of cm-super. Ah So I guess that is the answer)

Comment: I didn't have this problem with documents of class book. Only with beamer this happens. @R. Schumacher, what should I do to fix this permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the cm-super package then the bold p will be extracted from the type 1 font
sfso1000.pfb.

[image]